# Issue in file upload in Jmeter script

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing

As unable to record the application through JMeter recorder (encountered 401 Unauthorized while recording login), used Blazemeter Chrome plugin to record the script. But file upload is not getting successful during re-run. I have tried checking/unchecking "Use multipart/formdata" , provided details in File upload section of the transaction, used Java implementation but no luck.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP46r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEPjb.png)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot "suggest" anything without seeing the:

1. Response Data and headers - can be observed using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
2. Request Data and headers - the same listener can show you this
3. Values of any JMeter Variables used. Can be figured out from the request data but it's more convenient to use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

The most common reason for not being able to replay the recorded test script is missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) so ensure that your test is doing what it supposed to be doing since the very first request.

The approach of "checking/unchecking" and switching to different implementations is not very good, you should rather use a [sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) to capture the requests originating from JMeter and from the real browser, compare them and amend JMeter's configuration unless the requests would be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be correlated)

Comment: Added the suggested screenshots. Have compared with Fiddler requests, and the requests are same.